# Regex for this pattern

Tags: regex

i have a package structure that I want to match on.
it can be any letters and dots, but I want to filter on the last letters to only be .war or .jar.

examples that pass:

```
com.foo.bar.war
com.foo.jar
com.foo.war.war
```

examples that do not pass:

```
com.foo.bar.ear
com.foo.jar.me
com.foo.war.xyz
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this regexp `\.(w|j)ar$`

Answer (score 3):

```
/\.[wj]ar$/
```

the $ means 'end of line' so this only matches only lines that end with .[wj]ar

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
/.*(.jar|.war)$/gim
```